# Preventing body onload xss that is injected as a request parameter

Tags: xss, firefox, rails

I have a rails 4.0.1 app that allows locale as a request parameter. Here is what i saw when i tested my app on firefox;

```
http://localhost:3000/pages?locale=en_EN%22%3E%3Cbody%20onload=%22alert%28%27XSS%27%29
```

So Firefox executes body=onload when the page renders, if i run this request from Firefox browser sadly alerts xss in a dialog box when it loads!

Chrome doesn't even send the request and Safari says request failed which is good.

There is nothing harmful to backend with it but this request terribly effects client side!

Am i missing something to implement in my response headers? 
What is there to do in order to tell browser not to manipulate DOM with request parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it could be that you've got an instance of a known rails bug as there was recently an XSS issue in internationalization.  [CVE-2013-4991](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-security-ann/pLrh6DUw998)

In the first instance, if you can, I'd recommend upgrading to a patched version or applying the workaround in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the locale parameter, i checked my view file and saw that i have this part '<html lang="{{ locale }}">' that is printing the locale value without any sanitize process. I fixed it by filtering param values against html tags. And upgraded rails as well.